# How to "protect" certain fields (to avoid row spacing) in huge excel data set

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, excel-2016

I am having huge data set, and every-time I am adding new row into it (middle of the table), the tables on left and right side are disrupted. Is there any way to "lock" these tables during my edit or ? On protection sheet tab i cant find solution.

That red part is actually non-disturbed table (should be), but always getting one row of spacing when adding it, I have manually to select exactly which row and how many columns in the middle part, it is time consuming.

[image]

Comment: Don't add a full row, just insert cells in the columns necessary.

Comment: @SolarMike I know that, was thinking if there is possibility to "lock" it somehow, but obviously not.  

Thx anyways!